# Что за ошибки выдает WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

не могу понять,что за ошибку выдает вордпресс? в файле functions.php все в порядке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-content\themes\sparrow\functions.php:29) in C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-includes\functions.php on line 6029

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-content\themes\sparrow\functions.php:29) in C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-admin\includes\misc.php on line 1252

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-content\themes\sparrow\functions.php:29) in C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-admin\admin-header.php on line 9

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-content\themes\sparrow\functions.php:29) in C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-includes\option.php on line 961

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-content\themes\sparrow\functions.php:29) in C:\Users\tempe\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wp-dev\wp-includes\option.php on line 962

Comment: По легенде, если посмотреть, что написано в ошибке, то можно понять в чем проблема)

Answer (score 0):

В строке 29 вашей functions.php производится вывод на экран или возникает ошибка, которая выводится на экран. Это происходит слишком рано, до вывода заголовков http. Поэтому позже, когда ядро пытается вывести http-заголовки, возникает проблема.

Решение: вынесите ваш вывод в хук WordPress, например, init. Точнее сказать сложно, не видя вашего кода.

Comment: вот мой код functions.php http://codepad.org/whfahoYe

Comment: Приведённый код ошибок не вызывает. То ли кодировка не та (должно быть utf8 без BOM), то ли файл не тот.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте кодировку файла. Возможно она в Macintosh.

И проверьте звисимости в подключении скриптов:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/ Один из них точно нуждается в предварительной загрузке jQuery.